# page numbers in beamer output from R markdown

Tags: latex, r-markdown

I am trying to add page numbers to my beamer presentation. I am using the following code in Rmarkdown (see below). The problem is that the page numbers are cut off. I have tried using geometry to adjust the dimensions but i keep getting an error message that they are incompatible. Does anyone have any ideas? I have spent hours searching for a solution.

````
---
title: my title
author: "me"
date: "May 05, 2016"
output: beamer_presentation
header-includes:
- \usepackage{fancyhdr}
- \pagestyle{fancy}
- \fancyhead{}
- \fancyfoot{}
- \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
- \setbeamertemplate{footline}{\thepage}
---

Global Options
=======================================================

```{r global_options, include=FALSE}
# Setting up your workspace for standard figure output and exclusion of chunk codes, warnings, and messages unless otherwise specified:
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.width=6, fig.height=4, 
                      fig.path='Figs/', 
                      fig.show='asis', include=FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE)
```

```{r}
 library(knitr)
```

```{r cars, include=TRUE, echo=FALSE}
summary(cars)
```


# Including Plots


```{r pressure, echo=FALSE, include=TRUE}
plot(pressure)
```
````

Comment: Don't use [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr)...

Comment: @Werner What should I do instead? tried `- \useoutertheme{infolines}` instead but it gives me a lot of extra information I don't want

Comment: What happens when you drop all the `fancyhdr` stuff, but keep `\setbeamertemplate{footline}{\thepage}`?

Comment: @Werner I get the following error message `Error in yaml::yaml.load(enc2utf8(string), ...) : 
  Parser error: while parsing a block mapping at line 1, column 1did not find expected key at line 2, column 3
Calls: <Anonymous> ... yaml_load_utf8 -> mark_utf8 -> <Anonymous> -> .Call
Execution haltedError in yaml::yaml.load(enc2utf8(string), ...) : 
  Parser error: while parsing a block mapping at line 1, column 1did not find expected key at line 2, column 3
Calls: <Anonymous> ... yaml_load_utf8 -> mark_utf8 -> <Anonymous> -> .Call
Execution halted`

Answer (score 0):

As @Werner already said, you should not use `fancyhdr` with beamer, because beamer has its own mechanism for head and footline.

The easiest way to add page numbers to a beamer presentation is to use one of the predefined templates, e.g. `\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]`:

````
---
title: my title
author: "me"
date: "May 05, 2016"
output: 
  beamer_presentation:
    keep_tex: true
header-includes:
  - \setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
---

Global Options
=======================================================

```{r global_options, include=FALSE}
# Setting up your workspace for standard figure output and exclusion of chunk codes, warnings, and messages unless otherwise specified:
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.width=6, fig.height=4, 
                      fig.path='Figs/', 
                      fig.show='asis', include=FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE)
```

```{r}
 library(knitr)
```

```{r cars, include=TRUE, echo=FALSE}
summary(cars)
```


# Including Plots


```{r pressure, echo=FALSE, include=TRUE}
plot(pressure)
```
````