# Rmarkdown and Latex format citations with round paranthesis

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, citations

I feel like this is a straight forward thing, but everything I find doesn't quite get me what I want. I'm using [rmarkdown](/questions/tagged/rmarkdown) and knitting to a [latex](/questions/tagged/latex) `.pdf`. I'd like to have my in-text citations have `round ()` parenthesis instead of the block ones. The [yaml](/questions/tagged/yaml) below uses a `references.bib` file to correctly import the references. Is there anything I can do to easily change my parenthesis to round?

```
---
title: "Title"
author: "Author"
date: "16/03/2020"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    fig_caption: yes
    citation_package: natbib
  bibliography: references.bib  
editor_options: 
  chunk_output_type: console
---
```

I've used an approach [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/466819/use-round-brackets-instead-of-square-brackets-in-natbib-citations), but it returns an error:

> ```
> Error in yaml::yaml.load(..., eval.expr = TRUE) : 
>   Parser error: while parsing a block mapping at line 6, column 5 did not 
>   find expected key at line 7, column 30`
>
>     ---
>     title: "Title"
>     author: "Author"
>     date: "16/03/2020"
>     output: 
>       pdf_document:
>         fig_caption: yes
>       bibliography: references.bib  
>     editor_options: 
>       chunk_output_type: console
>     \usepackage[round]{natbib}
>     ---
> ```

Any ideas? Thanks for your suggestions / ideas...

Comment: You can't use square brackets in your rmarkdown header. A workaround is to "hide" the command in a header file. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/58673002

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following from your other answer.

Comment: If you save `\usepackage[round]{natbib}` in a file called `preamble.tex`, you can add `includes:
      in_header: preamble.tex`  to your markdown document

Comment: If you could make a [mre] that actually cites something and include the necessary bib entries to run it, I could try to make some working code example

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your attempt to include `\usepackage[round]{natbib}` in the rmarkdown header is that rmarkdown seems not clever enough to parse commands with optional arguments. One can trick it by hiding the command in a `.tex` file

```
---
title: "Title"
author: "Author"
date: "16/03/2020"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    fig_caption: yes
    includes:
      in_header: preamble.tex
bibliography: references.bib  
---

test [@knuth]
```

with `preamble.tex`

```
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
```

[image]

https://rstudio.cloud/project/1061588

Answer (score 0):

Using the `header-includes:` option should fix the issue.

```
---
title: "Title"
author: "Author"
date: "16/03/2020"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    fig_caption: yes
    citation_package: natbib
  bibliography: references.bib  
editor_options: 
  chunk_output_type: console
header-includes:
    - \usepackage[round]{natbib}
---
```